Strange caching of the Flying Press plugin
Such a problem: after installing the plugin Flying Press site works fast and productive, but after a while begins to slow down a lot for no particular reason. At the same time in top the load on resources is not maximum. It seems that as the number of cached pages increases, it starts to slow down. Another thing I noticed is that if the plugin is reloaded (turn off and on) then everything becomes normal again. What could be the problem? Maybe who has encountered? I use standard settings after installation. I didn't notice anything special in frontend error and debug.log. The upload to the log was 30 minutes ago and the site is slowing down right now. Before that I used WP-Rocket for caching. With it everything works stably without freezes, but it does not cache as well as Flying Press.
I looked at the logs and tried to find out what the problem was. I didn't see anything critical. Increased the somaxconn parameter according to advice from the Internet, the problem remained.
debug.log -

[05-Apr-2024 03:25:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/footer.php on line 402
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$email_company is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 77
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_method_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 78
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_object_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 79
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$taxation is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 80
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$instructions is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 81
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$check_data_tax is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 82
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on false in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(100) : eval()'d code on line 17
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on false in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(100) : eval()'d code on line 17
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on false in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(100) : eval()'d code on line 18
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on false in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(100) : eval()'d code on line 18
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$email_company is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 77
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_method_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 78
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_object_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 79
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$taxation is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 80
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$instructions is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 81
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$check_data_tax is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 82
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:24 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:25 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:25 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:25 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOODMART_Wpbcssgenerator::$_notices is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/themes/woodmart/inc/classes/Wpbcssgenerator.php on line 14
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:25 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WOOCOMPOSER_VC\Main::$enabled_vc_composer is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/WooComposer/includes/woocomposer-template.php on line 89
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$email_company is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 77
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_method_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 78
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$payment_object_ffd is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 79
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$taxation is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 80
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$instructions is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 81
[05-Apr-2024 03:25:26 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property WC_Tinkoff::$check_data_tax is deprecated in /var/www/greathope_ru_usr/data/www/greathope.ru/wp-content/plugins/tinkoff-woocommerce/wc-tinkoff.php on line 82


Ask the author but from my understanding you didnt setup Scheduled preload feature to be at times when there is less traffic. So while at first is fast then slows down is due to generating caches in the background and if your hosting is not that good performance wise can do that. Should be fine when all the content is cached ? But plugin support should help you with proper settings and tips what to do.
